# Send multiple records from MS Access to MS Outlook body

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

So I need assistance.  I am running data in MS Access 2013 and I have a table with multiple rows and columns.  What I am trying to do is take each row and taking only some of the columns and send the data to MS Outlook and paste it into the body.

The data constantly changes is size.  One week I might have 3 rows of data and some weeks 50 rows.  So what I am looking for from a data is this:

MS Access Table:

```
Account Number    Date     Time    Cust Status     Issue          Corr Action
123               3/1/16   8A      Open            Customer       Resolved
345               3/5/16   8:30P   Close           Cust. Called   Confirmed
```

MS Outlook:

```
Account Number: 123
Cust Status: Open
Date: 3/1/16

Issue: 
Customer

Corr Action:
Resolved

Account Number: 456
Cust Status: Closed
Date: 3/5/16

Issue: 
Cust. Called

Corr Action:
Confirmed
```

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
Public Sub SendEmail()
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim sMsgBody As String
    Dim aBody() As String


    Call AdoRecordset

    InitOutlook
    Set mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        mailItem.To = ""
        mailItem.CC = ""
        mailItem.Subject = "Escalations for the week"

        mailItem.Body = Issues
        mailItem.Display

    Set mailItem = Nothing
    CleanUp

End Sub

Private Sub CleanUp()
    Set outlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function AdoRecordset()
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "Select [Issue] From [Table];"
    rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs![Issue]
        Issues = Issues & rs.Fields(0).Value & vbCrLf
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the formatted text from AdoRecordset to the calling subroutine.

```
Public Sub SendEmail()

    sMsgBody = AdoRecordset()
    .
    .
    .
    MailItem.Subject = sMsgBody

End Sub

Function AdoRecordset() as String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "Select [Account Number], [Date], [Cust Status], [Issue], [Corr Action] From [Table];"
    rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For Each oFld In rs.Fields
            Select Case oFld.Name
                Case "Account Number", "Date"
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & oFld.Value & vbCrLf
                Case "Cust Status"
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & oFld.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                Case Else
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & vbCrLf & oFld.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            End Select
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    AdoRecordset = sResult
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I must not be getting it.  This is the entire code that I took from above.  Can you please show me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
*Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Private outlookNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Email As String
Dim Issues As String

Private Sub InitOutlook()
    ' Initialize a session in Outlook
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    'Return a reference to the MAPI layer
    Set outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Let the user logon to Outlook with the
    'Outlook Profile dialog box
    'and then create a new session
    outlookNamespace.Logon , , True, False
End Sub

Public Sub SendEmail()
Dim sMsgBody As String
Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
Dim sResult As Variant

    sMsgBody = AdoRecordset()
    'mailItem.Subject = sMsgBody
    InitOutlook
    Set mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        mailItem.To = ""
        mailItem.Subject = "Escalations for the week"

        mailItem.Body = sResult
        mailItem.Display

    Set mailItem = Nothing
    CleanUp

End Sub

Private Sub CleanUp()
    Set outlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function AdoRecordset() As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim oFld As Variant
    Dim sResult As Variant

    strSql = "Select [Account Number], [Dates], [Cust Status], [Issue], [Corr Action] From [Table];"
    rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For Each oFld In rs.Fields
            Select Case oFld.Name
                Case "Incident#", "Date Escalted"
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & oFld.Value & vbCrLf
                Case "Customer Status"
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & oFld.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                Case Else
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & vbCrLf & oFld.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            End Select
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    AdoRecordset = sResult
End Function*
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is what I have.  Can you fix it.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Private outlookNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Email As String
Dim Issues As String

Private Sub InitOutlook()
    ' Initialize a session in Outlook
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    'Return a reference to the MAPI layer
    Set outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Let the user logon to Outlook with the
    'Outlook Profile dialog box
    'and then create a new session
    outlookNamespace.Logon , , True, False
End Sub

Public Sub SendEmail()
Dim sMsgBody As String
Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
Dim sResult As Variant

    sMsgBody = AdoRecordset()
    'mailItem.Subject = sMsgBody
    InitOutlook
    Set mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        mailItem.To = ""
        mailItem.Subject = "Escalations for the week"

        mailItem.Body = sResult
        mailItem.Display

    Set mailItem = Nothing
    CleanUp

End Sub

Private Sub CleanUp()
    Set outlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function AdoRecordset() As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim oFld As Variant
    Dim sResult As Variant

    strSql = "Select [Account Number], [Dates], [Cust Status], [Issue], [Corr Action] From [Table];"
    rs.Open strSql, CurrentProject.Connection

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For Each oFld In rs.Fields
            Select Case oFld.Name
                Case "Account Number", "Dates"
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & oFld.Value & vbCrLf
                Case "Cust Status"
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & oFld.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                Case Else
                    sResult = sResult & oFld.Name & ":" & vbCrLf & oFld.Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            End Select
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    AdoRecordset = sResult
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Jules.  I actually got it to work because of what you provided.

Comment: In that case, can you accept my answer as the solution?  Thanks.